# Someone please explain me why return {1,3} in run() function throwing me error when it is working for return {a,b} for fun function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Someone please explain me why return {1,3} in run() function throwing me error when it is working for return {a,b} for fun() function

```js
    function fun(){
        let a =10
        let b=20
        return{ a,b};
    }
    
    function run(){
        return{ 1,3 };
    }

    console.log(fun());
    console.log(run());
```

**

```
output:
   return{ 1,3
             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11

[Program exited with exit code 1]
```

**

Comment: `{1, 3}` is not valid syntax. `{a, b}` _is_ valid syntax because it's shorthand for an actual object `{a: a, b: b}`

Comment: What did you expect that to do, exactly? [Object shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) only works with property names, which can't start with numbers.

Comment: If you really want your code to work you can use `return {1: 1, 3: 3}` instead. But I don't know the real use case you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

because in the first example

```js
return{
   a,
   b
   };
```

is just an ES6 shorthand for

```js
return {
  a: a,
  b: b
}
```

> In ES6, assigning a property value that matches a property name, you can omit the property value.

on the other hand

```js
return {
  1,3
}
```

cannot be returned because this is not the default Object syntax in JavaScript

You can read about Objects in more depth in [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/es6/es6_objects.htm)

Comment: It is because shorthand property names work only for variables not primitives.